# C : Copy shorter string into longer without using built in functions

Tags: c, string

the task in this is to copy the first `n` characters from (null terminated) string2 (`s2`) into `s1` while using pointers. I know how to copy the strings from one to another, but I am having issues with eliminating the extra values. For example:

```
s1= 'This is a test'
s2 = 'A test'

after copying, I am left with:

s1 = 'a tests a test'
```

Here is my code:

```
char *s1pointer;
const char *s2pointer;
int i;
int number_char_replace;

s1pointer = s1;
s2pointer = s2;
i=0;
number_char_replace = num; 

for(i=0;s1pointer[i] !='\0'||s2pointer[i]!='\0';i++)
{
s1pointer[i]=s2pointer[i];
}
}
```

This is homework, so please dont feel the need to just give me the answer. A hint for the logic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am surprised when OP says its homework and no one jumps out

Comment: I would say that the *real* problem here is that the OP didn't know that C strings need to be null-terminated.  Now is that his fault, or the professor's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to somehow indicate the end of the string after the for. Spoiler:

> `s1pointer[i] = 0;`

Comment: Woah. I did not know you could do that!

Comment: Thank you for the help, I now have this section of my code outputting what I need.

Comment: And on mobile, it says "Click for spoiler" (or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

Three problems:

1. Your target string is not zero terminated when your code finishes.  This can cause problems when, e.g., you try to print your string.  Also, when you are copying a smaller string on top of a bigger string, it will be impossible to know where the new contents end and the older ones continue.
2. I understand why you're testing `s2pointer[i] !='\0'` in your `for` loop; you want to stop when the source string is exhausted.  But why is `s1pointer[i] !='\0'` there too?  Do you need it?  Do you know anything about what `s1` contains before the copying starts?
3. You said that you wanted to copy up to `n` characters.  Where is that, in your code?

Comment: The s1pointer was an oversight, it didn't hurt my previous outputs in functions so I included it. I forgot including N in the process of trying to figure it all out...I lost the forest in the trees I guess. Let me try to figure out the logic keeping the n in mind.